# Display a table of the array keys and values in PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, html-table

Just wondering is there any way to display a numerically indexed array in a table format with the array keys and values?

I try to do the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
<body>
  <?php 
    $countries=array("United State","Canada","England","Russia","Japan");
  ?>
  <h2>Country List</h2>
  <?php 
    echo "<td>".(array_keys($countries,"United State"))."</td><td>".(array_values($countries))."</td>"; 
  ?>
</body>
```

Comment: so can i use the array_keys and array_values functions to do it?

Comment: Nope. The best way to do this would be using a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any array functions to achieve this. A `foreach` loop is all that's needed. Here's an improved version of your code with table styling too:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        table td,th {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        td {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <?php

    $countries = array(
        "United States",
        "Canada",
        "England",
        "Russia",
        "Japan"
    );

    ?>

    <h2>Country List</h2>

    <table>
        <th>SI No.</th>
        <th>Country Name</th>

        <?php

        foreach ($countries as $key => $value) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . ++$key . "</td>\n<td>" . $value . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }

        ?>
    </table>
</body>
```

[**Working demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/8DVtYw)

Comment: I dunno who he was, but you hit the nail on the head. Upvoted. Oh, JK - I'm not a registered user, so I can't upvote.

Comment: @Helpful: Maybe someone thought it was too basic. I'm okay with the downvote but wanted to find out if anything was wrong in my answer. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Thank you for ur help, I want to give the up-vote, but the system said I need to reach 15 reputation to do that :[ ..... and thank you for ur help again.

Comment: @AmalMurali May i know what is the purpose to add ++  like "++$key"? Thanks.

Comment: @Gem Array indexes in PHP start with 0, and I wanted to start with 1. `++$key` increments `$key` by one, then returns `$key`. You could achieve the same thing by adding `$key++` at the end of the loop as well.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the key increment as it will increment the last character of the key. I'm not sure why this happens, in any case, it's only applicable in a for loop and redundant in a foreach

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30792780)